# mod operation proof

Tags: modular-arithmetic, problem-solving

Prove:

$  ab\,\bmod\,d = ((a\,\bmod\,d)\,(b\,\bmod\,d))\,\bmod\,d $ where $a$, $b$ and $d$ are non-negative integers.

Reference : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Equivalencies

Context :
I was solving the problem 'C. DNA Alignment' in Codeforces Round #195(div.2).
To solve the problem, I had to calc (a^b)%n in Big-O(N) without overflow.
This could be done simply if above equation is always true.
I assumed this equality is always true and solve the problem.
But I couldn't prove my solution because of this equation, so I searched it but faild.
So I decided to ask the proof of this problem.

Problem Source : http://codeforces.com/contest/520/problem/C

Comment: Done, now what?

Comment: I wanted to prove "ab mod d = ((a mod d) * b) mod d" not "ab mod d=((a mod d)(b mod d))mod d" even they are mathematically same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=\alpha d+j, b=\beta d+k$. $a\mod d =j$, so the right hand side is:
$$jb\mod d=(j\beta d+jk) \mod d=jk \mod d$$.
Looking at the left hand side:

$$ab \mod d=(\alpha d+j)(\beta d+k)=\alpha\beta d^2 + \alpha dk + \beta dj + jk=jk \mod d$$

and these are equal.